# Need an FLV File for Experimentation

Tags: video-editing

This is not a video editing question per se, but I hope you'll indulge me because it does relate very closes.

For a work task I need to research conversion of flv files to something that can be used in HTML5 (mp4, webm). My problem is I need an flv file I can play with. I've been to a few open source movie sites but so far they seem to have converted already (or the links to flv sources are broken). Does anyone know where I can download an flv file?

UPDATE: Between posting and getting an answer, I realized this is exactly the wrong approach. My first thought should have been to get the source files the flvs were created from, and only convert directly from flv if I can't find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [flv-sample files](https://samples.ffmpeg.org/FLV/) of the ffmpeg project. [This](http://www.sample-videos.com/index.php#sample-flv-video/) is another site with sample videos of different resolution and sizes.

Comment: Didn't know there was one. Thanks.